# Cannot update software for my Mac mini?

Tags: macos, updates, mac-mini

I can't update the software i.e., Mac OS, iTunes, etc., in my Mac mini. Can anybody give the solution for my problem?

i update the software using the "software update" from the left most top the apple icon. The software size 1.17GB download successfully but error is "you can't save the installation file in your MacMini" This message is displayed on my screen

Please give me the solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: We need MUCH more detail. What did you try, what errors do you get, which version of OS X, ...? Please use the "edit" link to add more details, for otherwise this will quickly be closed.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to update your software? The easiest way is to select 'Software Update...' from the Apple menu in the top left corner of your screen. This does require an internet connection - I presume you were able to connect to the internet on your Mac Mini in order to post this. Does Software Update give any error messages?

Also, could your software be up to date already? What versions are you running? To get the version of Mac OS X that you're running, select 'About This Mac' from the Apple menu, and the version should be displayed immediately below the Apple logo and "Mac OS X". The latest version at time of writing is 10.6.6 - if you have that, you won't get any updates to Mac OS X, because there aren't any! Similarly, iTunes is at version 10.1.1, and will be updated by Software Update if you have an earlier version.

Comment: i try software update at the corner of the screen down the apple icon. i have proper internet connection but i can't

Comment: Why not? What error messages does Software Update give?

Comment: .."you can't save the installation file" This is the message

Comment: Do you have 1.17GB free on your hard disk? Have you tried repairing permissions on your startup disk with Disk Utility (in `/Applications/Utilities`)?

Answer (score 0):

Install them one by one. you need at least triple of that download size free and no other programs running.